# rvest log in to Yahoo for scraping

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from yahoo after logging in to my yahoo account. I've tried to follow the answers to [Using rvest or httr to log in to non-standard forms on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418770/using-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-non-standard-forms-on-a-webpage) and [Scraping password protected forum in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434478/scraping-password-protected-forum-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but after submitting the form I do not seem to be logged in and I get redirected back to the log in page.

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(rvest)
yahoo <- html_session("https://login.yahoo.com/")
form <- html_form(yahoo)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form, "username"="myusername", "passwd"="mypassword")
filled_form$url <- yahoo$url  # otherwise I get an error from no url
sess <- submit_form(yahoo, filled_form)
```

I should then be able to navigate to the personal information page and select a node that reads "Personal info":

```
sess %>%
    jump_to("https://login.yahoo.com/account/personalinfo") %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("h1") %>%
    html_text()
```

But instead, I just get "Sign in". One potential issue is with `submit_form()`, which seems to be using `passwd` rather than the correct submit button (`signin`). But when I try using `signin`, I get an error from `submit_form`:

```
sess <- submit_form(yahoo, filled_form, submit='signin')
```

gives "Error: Unknown submission name 'signin'.Possible values: passwd"

Any ideas for what I should be doing differently, or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure out what the problem was?